# How do I get selenium to open one browser and keep using that browser instead of loading a new browser for every url / scrape javascript

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code and I am trying to scrape a xls file I have to use selenium as far as I can tell.

The website uses the following code to get the file:

```
function GetQuote() {
          $('#lblError').html('');
          $('#lblError2').html('');
    if ($('#txtTicker') != null && $('#txtTicker').val() != null && $('#txtTicker').val().trim() != ''){
        trackGAEventGbl('quote-table-download', $('#txtTicker').val(), 'download');         
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            frm.action = window.location.pathname;
        }           
        frm.submit();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please enter a Stock or Index Symbol.');
        return false;
    }
  }
```

I have not had any luck scraping this without using selenium. However, I am finding the code takes ages to complete as I have a fair few companies I follow. But also Every time I scrape using selenium using the below code it opens and closes a new instance of chrome. Is there a way I can speed this up?

```
def get_file(ticker, url):
    chrome_driver_path=r"D:\Program Files\chromedriver\84\chromedriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('txtTicker')
    inputElement.send_keys(ticker)
    inputElement.submit()

    tickers = [line.rstrip() for line in open(r"C:\Python38\Projects\ticker_list.txt", "r")]
for ticker in tickers:

    get_file(ticker)
    if os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Downloads\quotedata.dat'):

        if os.stat(r'C:\Users\Downloads\quotedata.dat').st_size != 0:
            df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\quotedata.dat',
                        header=None, sep=',', engine='python',skiprows=2)
            new_header = df.iloc[0]
            df = df[1:]
            df.columns = new_header

            print(df)
            store_path = r"D:\Data\US\Option Data\{}\{} data.csv".format(ticker,ticker)
            print(store_path)
            df.to_csv(store_path, index = False)


        os.remove(r"C:\Users\Downloads\quotedata.dat")
        count = count + 1
        print("Processed {} / {} Tickers".format(count, len_tickers))
```

Comment: Please show you complete code, where do you use this `get_file` function?

Comment: I havent included the URL if you need it I can send over pm or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `driver` once at the beginning at your script and then use it in `get_file` function:

```py
chrome_driver_path=r"D:\Program Files\chromedriver\84\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=options)

def get_file(ticker, url):
  driver.get(url)
  ...

tickers = [line.rstrip() for line in open(r"C:\Python38\Projects\ticker_list.txt", "r")]
for ticker in tickers:
  get_file(ticker)
  ...
```